# Custom Drop down like layout

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

I want a custom layout drop down box for my app as if like i am on my homepage and i press a button that's in center of page and then this layout should appear after i press that button, i tried several other and searched the internet but i was unable to get an idea on how to make a drop down box like this : [image: drop down layout]

this shows like two kinds of layout first one we pick the date like 12 months in first column , then 1-31 numbers and then the year from 2001-2012, i don't get and idea that how can make this effect like glassy one i wanted to make like exact same layout as shown here, can any one please suggest me how to implement that coding will me much helpful.

Comment: If you want that, program for iOS instead of Android.

Comment: is that only for iOS can't i used it for android by any how i have seen some apps of android using that like "Best Voice Changer" is using this same layout for their android app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is  an example you can refer this one

http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

you can get source from here for that

http://android-wheel.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

another example

https://github.com/sys1yagi/AndroidPractice/tree/master/DrumPicker/trunk